# Is non-increasing the same as monotone decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, monotone-functions

My understanding of a non-increasing sequence is that for every $n$, $a_{n} \geq a_{n+1}$.

This appears to be the same definition as a sequence being monotone decreasing, except I don't understand why we would have two names for the same thing. I'm wondering if there's a subtle detail I'm missing in one of the definitions that is contributing to my confusion.

Comment: It's often the case that "monotone decreasing" entails *strictly* decreasing, whereas "(monotone) non-increasing" allows for intervals where the sequence is constant.  Because of the possibility of confusion, this should probably be spelled out explicitly for each text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some writers distinguish

- monotone decreasing : $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$, and
- strictly monotone decreasing : $a_n > a_{n+1}$.

Some writers use "monotone decreasing" to mean "strictly monotone decreasing" and others use it to mean non-strictly monotone decreasing, as recited above.

Some writers use the forms "strictly increasing", "increasing", "decreasing", and "strictly decreasing" in parallel with the above.  At least one writer I've read used "monotone" to mean strict and increasing/decreasing to mean non-strict.

I have, at times, wondered if any two humans can agree on which of these terms to use and what their exact meanings are.  Consequently, I have to check any author's definitions to make sure I know what they mean when they use these terms.

Answer (score 2):

There is two different systems of nomenclature.

$a_{n+1} \le a_n\quad$ ... $\quad a_{n+1} < a_n$

correspond, respectively, to

nonincreasing ... decreasing

or to

decreasing ... strictly decreasing

You must consult the book you are reading to find out which is used there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific difference. "Non-increasing" and "decreasing" can be used interchangeably as long as "strictly decreasing" (i.e. only decreases, as opposed to staying constant at some points) is separately defined.

However, from a language point of view, it would make more sense to describe a sequence that stays constant over a wider range as "non-increasing" and one that decreases almost everywhere as "decreasing".